# raphael canvas image not displaying correctly in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, raphael

I use a tachometer library for raphael: https://github.com/codefront/raphael.tachometer.js

In firefox and google chrome, it displays the background image correctly. It does not display correctly it in IE8 (as seen below).

[image]

Below is how it looks in FF and google chrome

[image]

```
#speedometer {
    background: transparent url('/assets/images/speedometer.png') no-repeat;
    width: 381px;
    height: 380px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    right: -20px;
}
```

calling a tachometer instance:

```
var t = Raphael('speedometer').tachometer(50, 
    {
        numberMin: 0,
        numberMax: 8000,
        interactive: true,
        scaleAngleStart: 77,
        scaleAngleEnd: 285,
        scaleWidth: 3,
        scaleLength: 10,
        frameSize: 6,
        boardAttr: {
          'stroke': 4,
      'fill': 'transparent',
      'opacity': '0.0'
        },
        frameSize: 6,
        outerFrameAttr: {
          'stroke': 'transparent',
          'stroke-width': 0.3,
      'fill': 'transparent',
      'opacity': '0.0'
        },
        innerFrameAttr: {
          'stroke': 'transparent',
          'stroke-width': 0.3,
          'fill': 'transparent',
      'opacity': '0.0'
        },
        needleAnimation: true,
        needleAnimationDuration: 6200,
        needleAnimationEasing: 'bounce',
    }
);

t.set(3400);
t.get();
```

The html that displays the speedometer is: `<div id="speedometer"></div>`

UPDATE: figured it out, I had to add 'opacity': '0.0' under each 'fill': 'transparent'. I updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: glad you solved it. Post the solution as an answer below, and mark it as 'Accepted' using the tick. That will help others on the site who find this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to add 'opacity': '0.0' under each 'fill': 'transparent'. I updated the code to reflect that.

```
var t = Raphael('speedometer').tachometer(50, 
{
    numberMin: 0,
    numberMax: 8000,
    interactive: true,
    scaleAngleStart: 77,
    scaleAngleEnd: 285,
    scaleWidth: 3,
    scaleLength: 10,
    frameSize: 6,
    boardAttr: {
      'stroke': 4,
      'fill': 'transparent',
      'opacity': '0.0'
    },
    frameSize: 6,
    outerFrameAttr: {
      'stroke': 'transparent',
      'stroke-width': 0.3,
      'fill': 'transparent',
      'opacity': '0.0'
    },
    innerFrameAttr: {
      'stroke': 'transparent',
      'stroke-width': 0.3,
      'fill': 'transparent',
      'opacity': '0.0'
    },
    needleAnimation: true,
    needleAnimationDuration: 6200,
    needleAnimationEasing: 'bounce',
});

t.set(3400);
t.get();
```